# iptables: Is it dangerous to filter by source port?

Tags: security, firewall, iptables

I would like to run a stateless firewall setup and I currently have the following rules:

```
#Do not track any packet
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j NOTRACK
COMMIT

#Actual firewall rules
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m multiport -p tcp --sport 80,443 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Now my question is, isn't it possible for an attacker to remotely access any service on my server so long as he makes that connection from his computer on a source port 80, 443 or 53?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These rules will allow any incoming packet, as long as it's origin port is 53 (UDP), 80 (TCP) or 443 (TCP). No matter what the destination port is. Thus your machine has all ports open for those packages. And the answer is **yes**.

A common `iptables` configuration would filter based in destination ports:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

UPDATE: As you noticed it uses the state machine. Without it the firewall can't keep track of already established TCP connections. The destination port (for example 80) is changed to something else by the server after taking the connection from the listening socket.

Comment: I think you missed the objective by avoiding the usage of "-m state" :) But thanks for clarifying. Guess it's back to the drawing board for me.

Comment: My answer to your question is still valid. You're right, I forgot the stateless requirement in my sample rules. But then, if you don't have the state machine there is no way the firewall can filter the kind of traffic a port 80 would receive. Since the destination port is changed by the server after attending the connection.

Comment: Exactly. I'll mark the updated answer as the correct answer. Thanks for the help o/

Comment: http://inai.de/documents/Perfect_Ruleset.pdf  " -m state: replaced by -m conntrack  -j NOTRACK: replaced by -j CT --notrack "